# Adding an element to a tree in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code for including the node of a tree into the current tree (the union method):

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

   def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
        {
         that.incl(this.elem)
         return that
        }
 def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  // Print the trending tweets
  val gizmodoTweets = TweetReader.ParseTweets.getTweetData("gizmodo", TweetData.gizmodo)
  val techCrunchTweets = TweetReader.ParseTweets.getTweetData("TechCrunch", TweetData.gizmodo)
  val test1: TweetSet = TweetReader.toTweetSet(gizmodoTweets)
  val test2: TweetSet = TweetReader.toTweetSet(techCrunchTweets)
  test1.union(test2).foreach(x=> println(x))
```

}

But when I print the output of the union method, I do not see the `this.elem` added to the `that` tree. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is that from coursera training, Course 1? Show as how you trying to print

Comment: added the code for printing...

Comment: Your incl function create new instance. So its not a modification. So your version is returning original paramter.

Comment: But aren't the objects passed by reference??

Comment: You do not modify your object anywhere. You are creating a new `TweetSet` with `new NonEmpty(elem, left, right)`.

Comment: Feel free to correct me. But in scala parameters could be pass by value or by name. Default behavior is by value.

Comment: Objects are not passed by reference. Their references are passed by value. That is a small, but very important difference.

Comment: But if we are passing the reference shouldn't it change the original object itself?

Comment: you can NOT change ( parameter | object) which is passed by value. That the whole idea of FP. So as the result new instance must create every time.

Comment: Yes, it will modify the object if you do it, but you are not changing the object anywhere.

Comment: Thank you understood your point...

Comment: If you are happy to spend month or two reading to see what this all com from: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `incl`-method returns a new set with the union of the two other sets, but you are throwing the result away and returning the parameter instead.

To fix it, change your union method to this:

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that.incl(this.elem)
```

Comment: But doesn't the statement `that.incl(this.elem)` modifies `that` which now includes the new element which then returned by the next statement.

Comment: No. `TweetSet` is immutable.

Comment: could you please help with a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810999/union-of-trees-in-scala