# Union of Trees in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to take union of two trees using the union method. For the purposes of checking the code I added the print statements inside the method. But the print of `acc` shows that it is not changing with the recrsion. I do not understand why is this happening. Can someone please explain.

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

    def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    {
      def unionRec(set:TweetSet,acc:TweetSet): TweetSet =
      {
        if (set.isEmpty)
          return acc
        else
        {
          acc.foreach(x=> println(x))
          println("####################")
          set.foreach(x=>println(x))
          println("####################")
          unionRec(set.takeRight,unionRec(set.takeLeft,acc.incl(set.rootTweet)))
          return acc
        }
      }
      unionRec(this,that)
    }

    def takeLeft: TweetSet =
    {
      return left
    }

    def takeRight: TweetSet =
    {
      return right
    }
    def rootTweet: Tweet =
    {
      return elem
    }
  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
  }
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = {
    f(elem)
    left.foreach(f)
    right.foreach(f)
  }
}
class Empty extends TweetSet {
 def isEmpty: Boolean = true
}
```

Comment: re: your usage of `return` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12560532/409976.

Comment: I know I could have omitted it for the methods...are you saying it is causing this issue?

Comment: @sarthak given the answer, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the exact same mistake as you did in your last question ([Adding an element to a tree in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803038/adding-an-element-to-a-tree-in-scala/40803131#40803131)). You are throwing away the result of your `unionRec`-call. Remember that `TweetSet` is immutable, so `acc` will never change!

These two lines:

```
unionRec(set.takeRight,unionRec(set.takeLeft,acc.incl(set.rootTweet)))
return acc
```

Has to be changed to this:

```
return unionRec(set.takeRight,unionRec(set.takeLeft,acc.incl(set.rootTweet)))
```

Comment: I did that initially, it also gave the same result, but for each iteration I am passing an `acc` which includes 1 extra element. But when I print the `acc` as shown in the method, in all the iterations I see the value of acc unchanged. This should not happen

Comment: I just ran your code with the change, and it worked.

Comment: Did you try to just print the result of the `union`-function instead of printing `acc` again and again?

Comment: I guess your problem must be somewhere else than the code you posted then, because that's the only mistake I can see in this code (and that mistake causes exactly the result you get).